# android - send nested jsonObject in web request

Tags: java, android, json

I used this code to send parameter

> {
>               "email":"email@domain.com",
>               "password":"pass"
>       }

```
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "email@domain.com"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass"));
```

but web developer change format to this format

> {
>           "data":{
>               "email":"email@domain.com",
>               "password":"pass"
>           }
>       }

how can I update my code to works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to works.

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
JSONObject jbj = new JSONObject();
jbj.put("email","email@domain.com");
jbj.put("password","pass");
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", jbj.toString()));
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this best practices but I approach that by create two jsonobject , and connect them by `accumulate` command

here is Example

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("email","email@domain.com");
json.put("password", "pass");

JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();
json2.accumulate("data",json);
```